# How to remotely control a TT6061A dimmer using an ESP8266 and detect its current state?

Tags: high-voltage, esp8266, capacitive

I am trying to remotely control a TT6061A (embedded inside an existing module), 3-way dimmer using an ESP8266. My goal is to set the device state to OFF, LOW, MEDIUM, or HIGH.

However, there is no documented feature to control the device beyond the capacitive touch control. I am considering modifying the capacitance on the touch input by connecting it to a pin on the ESP and toggling the state of the device from high impedance to LOW.

The challenge is detecting the device's current state to determine the number of times to toggle it. I have considered several options:

- Short the Vdd pin with an NPN via a pin on the ESP or a photo coupler to minimize the touch points with the high voltage circuit. This will reset it to a known state (LOW).
- Measure light intensity with a photo resistor.
- Measure the current on the live wires inductively using a coil and measuring the voltage in-series with a resistor using the analog-to-digital converter.
- Connect the TRIAC driver pin to an input on the ESP through a voltage divider.
- Emulate the TT6061A's functionality on the ESP device and let the ESP drive the state.

I am open to suggestions on the best approach to detect the device's current state and remotely control it.

Comment: why not use a Triac circuit and a zero crossing detector circuit (there are ready made modules) and have full control over dimming?

Comment: I am attempting modify an existing module that is using the TT6061A internally